# Core data find other users (fetch result controller) and add them

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, many-to-many

Hello I know that this question have many answers in here for sure but couldn't found nothing that have same problem as I got so...

Its look very complex but actually it's (The problem) very simple. So let me just start of with some photos and code and then explain my problem (which I'm pretty sure it very simple problem for those of you who are good with Core-Data).

1. Add friends VC Look Like this:

[Image_2](http://s8.postimg.org/vu2y5lxlx/Screen_Shot_2015_04_02_at_01_25_39.png)

[Image_3](http://s1.postimg.org/de5i162kv/Screen_Shot_2015_04_02_at_01_29_57.png)

1. Code for friend VC (Filter the friends by email) Just looking for other users stored in "Account Entity":

***-(void)filter:(NSString*)text***
    {

```
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create our fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // Define the entity we are looking for
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Define how we want our entities to be sorted
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:@"email" ascending:YES];

    // Define how we want our entities to be filtered
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email = %@)", text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


    if ([sortDescriptor isEqual:user_email]) {

        NSLog(@"ERORRRRRR SAME USER LOOKING FOR THE SAME USER");

    }
    else{
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }

    // If we are searching for anything...
    if(text.length > 0)
    {

    }

    NSError *error;

   NSArray* loadedEntities = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:loadedEntities];

    loadedEntities = filteredTableData;



    NSLog(@"%@",loadedEntities);



    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

No problem in here also as you can see in Image_2 it is working and finding other users on the app but now when trying to fetch those users to a new entity named 
Favorites its not working.

2. Moving on to second code still on Add friends VC:

   -(void)addFavorite{

   ```
       ///FIND OUR CORRUNET USER OF THE APP EMAIL AND FETCH IT TO THE VIEW CONTROLLER FIND FAVORITE FREINDS REQUEST...


       [self getemail];
       NSLog(@"%@",user_email);


       NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


       // Create our fetch request
       NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

       // Define the entity we are looking for
       NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                      entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];
       [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

       // Define how we want our entities to be sorted
       NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                           initWithKey:@"email" ascending:YES];
       NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
       [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
       // Define how we want our entities to be filtered
       NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email = %@)", user_email];
       [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

       NSArray *theaccount = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

       NSLog(@"%@",theaccount);



       NSManagedObject *favorites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favorites" inManagedObjectContext:context];


       filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

       [favorites setValue:self.filteredFavorites forKeyPath:@"favorites"];


       NSLog(@"%@",favorites);

       for (Favorites *favo in theaccount) {

           AccountBase *base = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];



           [favo addAccountBaseObject:base];

           }



       [self.tableView reloadData];
   ```
3. Account Base VC:

some code over there is :

```
- (void)addFavoriteObject:(Favorites *)value;
- (void)removeFavoriteObject:(Favorites *)value;
- (void)addFavorite:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeFavorites:(NSSet *)values;
```

So what do we got here?

first table view and looking for users on my app stored in entity name Account using core-data then trying to add this user to a new entity name Favorites with many-to many realationship to the first entity named Account,
***- The problem?***

Can't seem to understand how to use the relationship's the right way and using fetch controller delegate methods the right way to know which users added another user .

In another words I just want to add users to my app function just like all global well known applications do.
Simply search and add I tried here to use "NSset" but I cant seem to understand that my app keep crashing tried over and over.

How do you basically fetch your'e user to new entity named Favorites and then put all over your users Favorites freinds in there after you know its only Favorites freinds of him and not of a diffrent user

4. Crash Log Reason:

   `-[Account addAccountBaseObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` 0x7fab1062f6d0

2015-04-02 09:33:39.979 FavoritesTest[30386:719441] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Account addAccountBaseObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab1062f6d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0baa75 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dc73bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0c1d1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0199dc ___forwarding_** + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e019578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   FavoritesTest                          0x000000010a9541bf -[FilterDemoTableViewController addfavorite] + 1695
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c286a22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    7   FavoritesTest                          0x000000010a9d09f2 -[SCLAlertView buttonTapped:] + 546
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c286a22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c38de50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c38d21f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c634e80 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 9487
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c2cc856 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c2cd483 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c299fb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c2a7227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c28223c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfefc91 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfe5b5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfe5194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfe4bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f9f3a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010c285580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  FavoritesTest                          0x000000010a95bb73 main + 115
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f615145 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: What is the crash log message?

Comment: Added It now to the post take a look please..

Answer (score 0):

In the line `[favo addAccountBaseObject:base];`, the object `favo` is of type `AccountBase`, not of type `Favorite`. Objective-C (unlike Swift) offers no compile time type checking. So you can perfectly easily assign objects to variables of the incorrect type without receiving warnings or errors of any kind.

Then, when you try to treat the object as an instance of the type you intended (`Favorite`) in this case, the program crashes, because it isn't really a favorite and it doesn't implement the method you called (`addAccountBaseObject:`).

Your fetch request is initialized with an account entity:

```
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

then you execute it:

```
NSArray *theaccount = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Now `theAccount` is filled with as many `AccountBase` objects as match the predicate. Incidentally, `theAccounts` would be a less confusing name here.

Then you initialize a `Favorite` object and insert it into the context, and log its value, but don't do anything else.

Then comes the `for` loop with the crash:

```
for (Favorites *favo in theaccount) 
{
    AccountBase *base = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [favo addAccountBaseObject:base];

}
```

`favo` is an `Account`, hence the crash. Since I don't know the details of your data model, it's hard to say exactly what you should be doing here. Perhaps something like:

```
for (AccountBase *acc in theAccounts) 
{
    [favorites addAccountBaseObject:acc];
}
```

as you seem to be adding the account to a favorites object (this seems the wrong way round, intuitively - although as long as the relationship has an inverse I guess it doesn't matter too much).

one more thing - you would have got a much quicker answer to this if you posted a shorter question and formatted it more cleanly - you don't need the images or the code listing for the filter method. People are lazy and don't like reading long qs.

Also it seems odd that the class name for "Account" is `AccountBase`, not sure what's going on there - and I presume you're saving your context later on in this method.

Comment: AccountBase and Account same thing forget about it I just need to change some staff there. Thank you so much for your'e answer tried to do all of the things you said and I just can't figure out how do I simply set a relationship of the current user 
"Account" and is "Favorites" friends? I tried you're for statement but still the application get crash I. Yeah in *account "Array" its actually should be *account you are wrong since I run a predicate over there if you see "(%@ email , user_email) and It return the current user account in the "Log" therefore now how I set this array (account)?

Comment: Looking at it again, maybe it should be `[acc addFavoriteObject:favorites];` in the for loop. That makes much more sense - you're adding a favorites object to the account, not an account to the favorites

Comment: Ohh now we are getting some where but still crash take a look please: data: {
    account = nil;
    favorites = nil;
})
2015-04-03 16:11:21.811 App[34937:781476] -[Account addFavoriteObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7b354bd10
2015-04-03 16:11:21.819 App[34937:781476] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Account addFavoriteObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7b354bd10'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Weird, doesn't `Account` or (`AccountBase` - I'm assuming they're the same, have `- (void)addFavoriteObject:(Favorites *)value;` declared on it. if you've changed the db you'll need to reset the simulator/delete the app from the device, also clean the build

Comment: Yeah very weird and yes AccountBase have this method there and also it still isn't working even after restarting the app clean and etc.I just don't get it way did apple made it so hard to make a simple relationship between two entities? :(

Comment: The stack trace says the object is of type `Account` not `AccountBase` - maybe that's the problem - do you have an `Account` object (perhaps without the method)as well as `AccountBase` in the project. Maybe try deleting the existing object and recreating it. Core Data is without doubt a pain in the ass.

Comment: look this is way I have account + accountBase http://josee.me/2012/03/16/core-data-passwords-in-keychain/                          btw for accountBase.m what should I do for the void method of add favorite object? maybe thats the problem?